# SQL-Server query to select last and previous information for multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

After looking in Stackoverflow I cant find a solution to this problem.

I'm using this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM(
     SELECT DISTINCT *  
     FROM Table_01
     ORDER BY ID, StartDate
     UNION ALL(
     SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Table_02
     ORDER BY ID, StartDate
    )
    UNION ALL (...
    ) a ORDER BY a.ID, a.StartDate
```

I got something like this, for each ID i would like to keep the last and previous date and other columns, to record a history

```
+------+------------+-----------+-------+-------+
|  ID  | StartDate  | EndDate   | Value | rate   |
+------+------------+-----------+-------+-------+
|   1  | 2018-06-29 |2018-10-22 |   15  | 77.2   |
|   1  | 2018-04-28 |2018-06-21 |   23  | 55.3   |
|   1  | 2018-02-24 |2018-04-15 |   41  | 44.3   |
|   1  | 2017-06-29 |2017-11-29 |   55  | 44.1   |
|   2  | 2018-07-29 |2018-11-22 |   15  | 106.1  |
|   2  | 2018-03-28 |2018-07-21 |   23  | 10.8   |
|   2  | 2017-12-28 |2018-03-28 |   22  | 11.0   |
|   3  | 2017-09-28 |2018-01-28 |   11  | 87.09  |
|   3  | 2017-06-27 |2018-09-28 |   58  | 100    |
|  ... |    ...     |    ...    |  ...  | ...    |
+------+------------+-----------+-------+--------+
```

And I would like to have the next table, to keep the previous information

```
+------+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+-------+--------+-------+--------+
|  ID  | StartDate  | EndDate   | StartDateP | EndDateP  | Value | rate   | ValueP| rateP  |
+------+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+-------+--------+-------+--------+
|   1  | 2018-06-29 |2018-10-22 | 2018-04-28 |2018-06-21 |   15  | 77.2   |   23  | 55.3   |
|   2  | 2018-07-29 |2018-11-22 | 2018-03-28 |2018-07-21 |   15  | 106.1  |   23  | 10.8   |
|   3  | 2017-09-28 |2018-01-28 | 2017-06-27 |2018-09-28 |   11  | 87.09  |   58  | 100    |
|  ... |    ...     |    ...    |    ...     |    ...    |  ...  | ...    |  ...  | ...    |
+------+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+-------+--------+-------+--------+
```

Comment: What problem? Did you have a question?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want the row with the latest start date combined with the row with the startdate just before that? This might do the trick

```
WITH results AS
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY StartDate DESC) r
  FROM (
    -- start of your original query
    SELECT DISTINCT *
    FROM Table_01
    ORDER BY ID, StartDate

    UNION ALL

    (
       SELECT DISTINCT *
       FROM Table_02
       ORDER BY ID, StartDate
    )

    UNION ALL

    (...) a
    ORDER BY a.ID, a.StartDate

    -- end of your original query
  )
)
SELECT 
   r1.id, r1.startDate, r2.enddate, 
   r2.startDate startDateP, r2.enddate enddateP, 
   r1.value, r1.rate, 
   r2.value valueP, r2.rate rateP 
FROM results r1
LEFT JOIN results r2 ON r2.id = r1.id AND r2.r = 2
WHERE r1.r = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using `Row_Number()` in concert with a conditional aggregation

**Example**

```
Select ID 
      ,StartDate  = max(case when RN=1 then StartDate end)
      ,EndDate    = max(case when RN=1 then EndDate end)
      ,StartDateP = max(case when RN=2 then StartDate end)
      ,EndDateP   = max(case when RN=2 then EndDate end)
      ,Value      = max(case when RN=1 then Value end)
      ,Rate       = max(case when RN=1 then Rate end)
      ,ValueP     = max(case when RN=2 then Value end)
      ,RateP      = max(case when RN=2 then Rate end)
 From  (
        Select *
              ,RN = Row_Number() over (Partition By ID Order by EndDate Desc) 
         From  YourTable
       ) A
 Group By ID
```

**Returns**

[image]